# Eclipse: ignore thymeleaf attributes during XML validation

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf for XML templating. 
Eclipse correctly reports disallowed attributes, like

```
<signaturId th:object="${myVal}">
```

results in

```
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'th:object' is not allowed to appear in element 'signaturId'.
```

**Is it possible to ignore / suppress these errors**, either by allowing `th:` attributes everywhere or by disabling attribute validity in total?